# ASP.NET API App in Azure App Service

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, api, azure

I'm trying to "connect the dots here", I'm build a small solution as a school project. The flow should look like this:

1. School personel add "company info" into a Windows desktop client.
2. The Windows desktop client uses a Azure SQL Server as a DB
3. An Azure API App is used to consume data from that Azure SQL DB
4. A ASP.NET Web App should consume data from the created Azure API App

The Web App is used by the students to view "company info".

Is this the right path to go, or am I missing something?

Comment: Unfortunately there's no way to answer this on StackOverflow, as there isn't a single right answer. There are *lots* of ways to build apps with API's, whether using an API app or any other technique to host an API. And your desktop app could either talk directly to your database or it could use the same API the web app is using. Lots of options for database as well: Azure SQL Database service is certainly *an* option but not the *only* option. There is no *right* path to go...

Answer (score 2):

You have your architecture a little bit wrong here.  The way you should build it is:

1. Api App acts like a gateway between your client applications and the SQL database.
2. Your client applications (phones, desktop clients, embedded devices, what have you) access the database through the Api gateway.

The reason you do this is to protect your access credentials, primarily your sql connection string when you deploy the application out to production scenarios.

This video is part 3 in a training series, the access layer (unit tests in this case) should be the api endpoint for your service.
https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/raw-tech/AI-Part-3-Entity-Framework-and-Unit-Tests

You can also reference: https://github.com/drcrook1/Nerds4Hire/blob/master/NerdsForHire/NerdsForHire.Services/Controllers/NerdController.cs